# Inserting an item in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, winrt-xaml, itemscontrol

Here are the requirements.

In my `ItemsControl` (you can use a `ListView` if it helps you to consider the scenario). I want to inject, not a record, but a unique DataTemplate into an arbitrary indexed location in my list.

For example, I might want to insert it into the first position, index 0, or the third position, index 2, or perhaps even have the logic to insert it into the last position, index count-1.

I will need to sub-class ListView to accomplish this, I realize. That being said, I could easily create the SpecialItemTemplate, SpecialItemIndex DP properties to have the values.

Added requirements:

1. Don't require a special type of collection
2. Don't require manipulating the existing data
3. Allow the IsHitTestVisible to be variable, too

Any ideas how to accomplish this feat (in WinRT)?

Comment: Are you doing virtualization in this scenario Jerry? ....and ya just had to pick a Friday to ask. :P

Comment: I think this would not be very compat with virtualization. So, to keep it simple, let's say no. There's a way to do this, right? I just know there is.

Comment: Chris you figure this out in a real way, and not a hack way, and I will send you a Lumia 820 and a Microsoft shirt as a thank you. No kidding. How's that for ruining your weekend?

Comment: How about using an adapter that produces a second list that you'd bind to the ListView? Does WinRT even support implicit templates?

Comment: Eh, I took a 10min stab at it but the RT part has proven interesting and so far unfruitful. Except this weekend is weddings, birthdays, chores, and Royals games and I have an 820 and a shirt already but I'll swing back when time provides if not just for the public challenge and see if we cant sort something.  :)

Comment: Oh I think I solved this quite a while back with a nice `Behavior<ItemsControl>` (albeit for the desktop-browser-silverlight, not the mobile stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is basically a `Behavior` with a `Template` property which can be attached to any `ItemsControl`. I tested it with virtualizing and non-virtualizing panels, works for both cases. If you think the code is convoluted... well I can't disagree, wrote it a while back and I can't remember what reasons I had to write it the way it ended up.

Usage:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <AlternativeItemTemplate Index="42">
            <DataTemplate>
                ...foo...
            </DataTemplate>
        </AlternativeItemTemplate>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...bar...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

and the classes:

```
[ContentProperty( "ItemTemplate" )]
public class AlternativeItemTemplate : ItemContainerDecorator
{
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue( ItemTemplateProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ItemTemplateProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ItemTemplate", typeof( DataTemplate ), typeof( AlternativeItemTemplate ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

    public int Index
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue( IndexProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( IndexProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Index", typeof( int ), typeof( AlternativeItemTemplate ), new PropertyMetadata( -1 ) );

    protected override void OnContainersChanged()
    {
        if (!AssociatedObject.Items.Any() || Index < 0 || Index >= AssociatedObject.Items.Count)
        {
            ItemContentPresenter = null;
            ItemContentControl = null;
            m_overwrittenTemplate = null;
            return;
        }

        TryUpdateItem( ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem( AssociatedObject.Items[Index] ) );
    }

    private ContentPresenter ItemContentPresenter { get; set; }
    private ContentControl ItemContentControl { get; set; }
    private DataTemplate m_overwrittenTemplate;

    private void TryUpdateItem( DependencyObject itemContainer )
    {
        if (itemContainer == null)
        {
            ResetOverwrittenTemplate();
        }

        var containerAsPresenter = itemContainer as ContentPresenter;
        if (containerAsPresenter != null) UpdateItemContentPresenter( containerAsPresenter );
        else
        {
            var containerAsControl = itemContainer as ContentControl;
            if (containerAsControl != null) UpdateItemContentControl( containerAsControl );
        }
    }

    private void ResetOverwrittenTemplate()
    {
        if (ItemContentPresenter != null)
            ItemContentPresenter.ContentTemplate = m_overwrittenTemplate;

        if (ItemContentControl != null)
            ItemContentControl.ContentTemplate = m_overwrittenTemplate;

        ItemContentPresenter = null;
        ItemContentControl = null;

        m_overwrittenTemplate = null;
    }

    private void UpdateItemContentPresenter( ContentPresenter container )
    {
        if (ItemContentPresenter != null)
            ItemContentPresenter.ContentTemplate = m_overwrittenTemplate;

        ItemContentPresenter = container;
        m_overwrittenTemplate = ItemContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
        ItemContentPresenter.ContentTemplate = ItemTemplate;
    }

    private void UpdateItemContentControl( ContentControl container )
    {
        if (ItemContentControl != null)
            ItemContentControl.ContentTemplate = m_overwrittenTemplate;

        ItemContentControl = container;
        m_overwrittenTemplate = ItemContentControl.ContentTemplate;
        ItemContentControl.ContentTemplate = ItemTemplate;
    }
}

public abstract class ItemContainerDecorator : Behavior<ItemsControl>
{
    private Dictionary<object, DependencyObject> LastKnownContainers = new Dictionary<object, DependencyObject>();

    protected ItemContainerGenerator ItemContainerGenerator { get { return (AssociatedObject != null) ? AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator : null; } }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += HandleItemsChangedInitially;

        if (!TryAddObservers())
        {
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += AddObserversOnLoaded;
        }

        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnItemsControlLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += OnItemsControlLayoutUpdated;

        CheckContainersChanged();
    }

    private void OnItemsControlLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        CheckContainersChanged();
    }

    private void OnItemsControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckContainersChanged();
    }

    private void AddObserversOnLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AddObserversOnLoaded;
        TryAddObservers();
    }

    private bool TryAddObservers()
    {
        const bool success = true;
        Panel itemsHost =
            AssociatedObject.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<Panel>().FirstOrDefault( panel => panel.IsItemsHost );

        if (itemsHost != null)
        {
            var virtualizingItemsHost = itemsHost as VirtualizingPanel;
            if (virtualizingItemsHost != null)
            {
                virtualizingItemsHost.LayoutUpdated += OnVirtualizingItemsHostLayoutUpdated;
                m_virtualizingItemsHost = virtualizingItemsHost;
            }
            return success;
        }
        return !success;
    }

    private VirtualizingPanel m_virtualizingItemsHost;
    private bool LayoutUpdatedOccurredFirst;

    private void OnVirtualizingItemsHostLayoutUpdated( object sender, EventArgs eventArgs )
    {
        LayoutUpdatedOccurredFirst = true;
        CheckContainersChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged -= HandleItemsChangedInitially;
        ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged -= HandleItemsChanged;

        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnItemsControlLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= OnItemsControlLayoutUpdated;

        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AddObserversOnLoaded;
        if (m_virtualizingItemsHost != null) m_virtualizingItemsHost.LayoutUpdated -= OnVirtualizingItemsHostLayoutUpdated;
        m_virtualizingItemsHost = null;

        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void HandleItemsChangedInitially( object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged -= HandleItemsChangedInitially;

        if (!LayoutUpdatedOccurredFirst)
        {

            //sometimes calling UpdateLayout throws an ArgumentException
            //don't know why so we just swallow it
            //it's not particularly important
            try
            {
                AssociatedObject.UpdateLayout();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException) { }
        }

        ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += HandleItemsChanged;
        CheckContainersChanged();
    }

    private void HandleItemsChanged( object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        CheckContainersChanged();
    }

    private void CheckContainersChanged()
    {
        var newestContainers = new Dictionary<object, DependencyObject>();
        foreach (var item in AssociatedObject.Items)
        {
            newestContainers[item] = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem( item );
        }

        if (!LastKnownContainers.SequenceEqual( newestContainers ))
        {
            LastKnownContainers = newestContainers;
            OnContainersChanged();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnContainersChanged();
}
```

Comment: This is going to take some time to parse. Does it work if the data source is not observable? Does it override a record or push it out?

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT: It does work with any data source, there are no assumptions about the environment except that the associated object must be an `ItemsControl`. No, it does not override/push out any records, in fact all records are unchanged. It searches for the visual representation of an item (known as the `itemcontainer`) and changes its `Template`, that's all (it even restores the old template later)

Comment: Ah, yeah. Honestly I think that may be the only viable approach. So if I have 5 records showing and I inject one with your behavior this way, then I only have 4 records showing plus the custom template, right?

Comment: It dawns on me that I might have misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish. My custom behavior is intended to display an arbitrary record of the collection with an alternate version of the itemTemplate, but it is still meant to be shown as a record nonetheless. Now I begin to think that's not what you need, you want to sneak in some stuff (like a message "following items are less important"). Well, if this is the case I would recommend a completely different approach. Let me know if that's the case, and I'll try to draft my idea for you.